# Programmatic Pattern of Generating Images

Tags: image, image-processing, imagick

I know its possible with Barcoding, as is with the 2D 3D formats.

But one question left me astound and dumbfounded for the last 2 years ago. Was how do Github and other Forum Sites, Generate their Default Profile Picture? Might help if answered with Keywords, asides the real deal, I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Look up what SVG is (Scalable Vector Graphic)

Comment: Okay. Nice, Thanks for the quick reply. :)

Comment: Just for reference, they call it "Identicon" and here's a ruby example https://github.com/victorgama/identicon

Comment: Nice. :) Exactly what I was looking for. :P Thanks mate. ^^